# Proving English proficiency for my Canada Citizenship application

Tags: canada, citizenship

I have completed four years in Canada and as a permanent resident, I was thinking of applying for citizenship. Do I need to do a test to prove my English speaking skills? I scored 109/120 on a TOEFL internet based test 12 years ago and I have a Masters degree from the UK. Being from a non- English speaking country, should I still prove my proficiency in English? If so, what are cheap options I can use to fulfill the requirement.

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: That I most probably might need to do it. I am looking for validation or anything that I could substitute for a qualification

Comment: Section 15 on this page https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-0002-application-canadian-citizenship-under-subsection-5-1-adults-18-years-older.html#Step4 might be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> I scored 109/120 on a TOEFL internet based test 12 years ago

Now, the 12 years ago won't matter, my ten year old IELTS test was accepted just fine but https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=572 doesn't list the TOEFL and states

> We don’t accept any other third-party test results, even if they’re similar.

Continuing on,

> I have a Masters degree from the UK

That's great! https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=573 says

> You may send a transcript, diploma or certificate showing that you graduated from a secondary school or from a post-secondary program in Canada or abroad. These materials must show that the program was in English or French. A single course in an official language is not enough to meet this requirement.

Wishing you best of luck.